# Adding a SSL certificate to an Express Site

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have a small site that I have been tasked with adding an ssl certificate to. The site runs in express with this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('one-west-end'),
    app = require('../app'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    https = require('https'),
    express = require('express');

var keyPath = '../ssl/key.key';
var certPath = '../ssl/cert.crt';
var caPath = '../ssl/cert.crt';

var port = 3000;

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    port = 80;
}

if (fs.existsSync(keyPath) && fs.existsSync(certPath)) {
    port = 443;

    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(keyPath),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(certPath),
    };

    var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function(){
      console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
    });

} else {

    var server = app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
        debug('Express server listening on port ' + port);
    });

}
```

I did not create the necessary files to create the files but this is the [guide](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/generate-a-csr-with-openssl) that was used, which essentilly calls for:

```
> openssl genrsa -out ~/domain.com.ssl/domain.com.key 2048`
> openssl req -new -key ~/domain.com.ssl/domain.com.key -out ~/domain.com.ssl/domain.com.csr`
```

The only thing that I receieved from the person who bought the certificate was a zip file containg two `.crt` files. The content for one is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And the other one

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I'm using the key file created on in the initial step in the express file, but I'm not sure what file is my CA and which one is my cert. I have tried a few different variations, but I always seem to get a "This webpage is not available" error in chrome.

Comment: This [article](http://greengeckodesign.com/blog/2013/06/15/creating-an-ssl-certificate-for-node-dot-js/) may be of help.

Comment: You need crt-bundle file and I see you have not created SSL chain as well. Test SSL of your website here https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Answer (score 0):

The first file is likely your certificate, and the second file contains the CA chain.  Node requires each certificate in the CA chain to be passed **separately** in an array.  It does not support multiple concatenated certificates in a single file.

Each certificate needs to be put in its own file (ie `ca1.crt`, `ca2.crt`, and `ca3.crt`) and read separately.

```
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('domain.com.key'),
    certificate: fs.readFileSync('domain.com.crt'),
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('ca1.crt'), fs.readFileSync('ca2.crt'), fs.readFileSync('ca3.crt')]
});
```